# leaflet label line feature using streetlabels plugin

Tags: leaflet, labellines

I would like to label some lines on a webmap using leaflet. There is a plugin "streetlabels" which should do that. The property "cost" of response.table2 shall be displayed as label on the map. I am not quite sure how to do that. The other two layers shall not be labelled.
In my index.html file I referenced

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/Canvas-TextPath/master/ctxtextpath.js"></script> 
<script src='dist/L.LabelTextCollision.js'></script>
<script src='dist/Leaflet.streetlabels.js'></script>
```

Thats what I tried without success. No labels appear. How do I apply the renderer to geojsonLayerTable2?

```
// streetLabelsRenderer 
var streetLabelsRenderer = new L.StreetLabels({
    collisionFlg: true,
    propertyName: 'cost',
    showLabelIf: function (layer) {
      return true; //layer.properties.type == "primary";
    },
    fontStyle: {
      dynamicFontSize: false,
      fontSize: 10,
      fontSizeUnit: "px",
      lineWidth: 4.0,
      fillStyle: "black",
      strokeStyle: "white",
    },
  });


// Leaflet-map
var map = L.map('map',{
        renderer: streetLabelsRenderer}
        ).setView([48.200, 11.593347],17); 

// OpenStreetMap als Basiskarte hinzufügen
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors',
    maxNativeZoom:19,
    maxZoom:25
}).addTo(map);


// change marker
function punktmarker( feature, latlng ){
  // Change the values of these options to change the symbol's appearance
  let options = {
    radius: 5,
    fillColor: "lightgreen",
    color: "black",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
  }
  return L.circleMarker( latlng, options );
}


// reference to database request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'html_database1.php', true);



xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        
        
        //Lagerflächen
        var geojsonLayerTable1 = L.geoJSON(response.table1, {
            style: function (feature) {
            return {
              color: 'brown', 
              weight: 1 
              };},           
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.bezeichnung,{permanent: true, direction: 'right'}).openTooltip();
        }});
        
        
        //this layer should be labelled
        var geojsonLayerTable2 = L.geoJSON(response.table2, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  
                layer.bindPopup('id: ' + feature.properties.id + '<br>meter: ' + feature.properties.cost);
            }
        });
        
        
        //data
        var geojsonLayerTable3 = L.geoJSON(response.table3, {
            pointToLayer: punktmarker, 
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {  
                layer.bindPopup('ID: ' + feature.properties.id );
            }
        });
        
                
        //layer control
        var overlays = {
            'Lager': geojsonLayerTable1,
            'Transportstrecken': geojsonLayerTable2,
            'Edge table': geojsonLayerTable3
            };

        // add layer control
        L.control.layers(overlays).addTo(map);
    
        
    
    } else {
        console.error('Fehler bei der Anfrage');
    }
};




xhr.send();
```

Thanks for any help.